# Use jest.mock with Storybook

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, storybook

I need some help with Storybook.

I need to use a mock `jest.mock` in my storybook file.
See the code above

```
export default {
    title: 'MyStory',
    component: MyComponent,
    decorators: [withKnobs],
};
jest.mock('@my-custom-package/lib', () => mockFactory());

export function Demo() {
 
    return (
        <MyComponent
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            value={value}
            onChange={setValue}
        />
    );
}
```

When I run npm run storybook, I've got this error: **jest is not defined**

This is my main.ts file

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    features: {
        babelModeV7: true,
    },
    stories: [
        '../../../my-project/src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
    ],
    addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-knobs'],
    framework: {
        name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
        options: { fastRefresh: true },
    },
    webpackFinal: (config: any) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.scss$/u,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        });
        config.plugins.push(new Dotenv());
        // Return the altered config
        return config;
    },
};
```

I don't know where I should add some configuration for jest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the mock object of jest object separately for being able use it in browser environment.

```js
import jestMock from "jest-mock"

const fn = jestMock.fn()
```